# Unable to terminate delegating and transfer tezos out of Galleon app

Tags: baking, tezos-client, delegating, delegation

I’m can’t seem to find a way to terminate delegation and transfer my tezos out of the Galleon app because I want to sell the tokens. Using version 1.4.1b. I have more than enough balance to cover fees and I have tried to transfer to a new address only to have the app do nothing at all. Any answers please?

Comment: This site is for technical questions for developers and builders, its not intended for support for apps. Specific issues with Galleon should be directed to their support (their forum or twitter) found on their site: https://cryptonomic.tech/galleon.html . In general, note that if you have your seed phrase, you can easily import the wallet into any other app. If its an app specific issue you can try another. Also note that theres no real need to terminate delegation. While delegating you can transfer everything except 0.000001 XTZ from your wallet. It costs more than that to undelegate